# Send HTTP request with "Negotiate Authorization"

Tags: c#, .net, http, authentication

How can I send an HTTP request with Negotiate Authorization header attribute from a .NET (C#) application?

I tried the following, but Authorization attribute was not added to the request...

```
...
string url = ...;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Credentials = GetCredential();
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
...

private CredentialCache GetCredential()
{
    string url = ...;

    CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
    credentialCache.Add(new System.Uri(url), "Ntlm", new NetworkCredential(username, pwd, domain));
    return credentialCache;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My experience with using a network credential in a WebRequest is that the `request.GetResponse()` does NOT pass the credential unless it receives an Unauthorized (challenge) response from the server. If it does receive a 403, it will automatically fire a second request which includes the credential. Make sure the end point you are hitting returns a 401 if the Auth header is missing.

Comment: It returns 401 :(

Comment: My apologies - I meant to say 401 in my response, not 403. Your service should automatically fire a second request containing the Authorization Header if it receives a 401